# extracting sdf files from pubchem matching a monoisotopic mass

Tags: java, python, scientific-computing, pubchem, cheminformatics

I'm trying to extract the chemical structures from the pubchem database in the sdf format of compounds matching a certain exact mass and in the range of 10ppm of that exact mass(exactmass-cmpndmass/exactmass)*10^6. Is there a way to achieve this using python or java programming languages interfacing with pubchem.

Answer (score 1):

PubChem has a REST API to download chemical structures. In order to retrieve PubChem compound records within a given mass range, an Entrez query should be initiated to generate the list of CIDs.100:100.01 is the mass range for the  example.

```
http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pccompound&usehistory=y&retmax=0&term=100:100.01[exactmass]
```

you can refer this tutorial
[Power user gateway](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug_rest/PUG_REST_Tutorial.html)